# PHP foreach not looping through nested array

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I'll start by saying I'm new to PHP, but managed to hack together this foreach loop that runs through an array, but nothing is displaying and i'm getting an error saying 'invalid argument supplied for foreach()'.

The idea is that it should show 3 projects at random without repeating them and if the page URL matches the project_url variable, that particular project won't be shown.

Tried searching for similar issues but can't seem to find anything that fits my case as far as I can tell with my limited knowledge. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<?php

$recent_projects = array(
        array(
            project_img         => 'assets/img.jpg',
            project_title       => 'Project Name',
            project_cat         => 'Project Category',
            project_url         => 'project-name',
            project_alttag      => 'Project Name',
            project_titletag    => 'Project name',
            project_nofollow    => 'follow'
        ),
        array(
            project_img         => 'assets/img.jpg',
            project_title       => 'Project Name',
            project_cat         => 'Project Category',
            project_url         => 'project-name',
            project_alttag      => 'Project Name',
            project_titletag    => 'Project name',
            project_nofollow    => 'follow'
        ),
        array(
            project_img         => 'assets/img.jpg',
            project_title       => 'Project Name',
            project_cat         => 'Project Category',
            project_url         => 'project-name',
            project_alttag      => 'Project Name',
            project_titletag    => 'Project name',
            project_nofollow    => 'follow'
        ),
        array(
            project_img         => 'assets/img.jpg',
            project_title       => 'Project Name',
            project_cat         => 'Project Category',
            project_url         => 'project-name',
            project_alttag      => 'Project Name',
            project_titletag    => 'Project name',
            project_nofollow    => 'follow'
        )
    );

    $show_x_projects  = 3; // How may projects to show
    $i                = 0;
    $current_page     = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
    $random_projects  = array_rand($recent_projects);

?>
```

```
      <?php foreach($random_projects as $recent_projects):
        $item = (object)$recent_projects;
        if($current_page == $item->project_url) continue;
        $i++;
        if($i >= $show_x_projects) continue; ?>


          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <figure>
              <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $item->project_img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->project_alttag; ?>" title="<?php echo $item->project_titletag; ?>">
              <figcaption>
                  <h4><span><?php echo $item->project_title; ?></span></h4>
                  <p><?php echo $item->project_cat; ?></p>
                  <a href="<?php echo $item->project_url; ?>" rel="<?php echo $item->project_nofollow; ?>"></a>
                  <p class="view-project-link">View Project →</p>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where's the code to compare the page URL against the project URL?

Comment: `array_rand($recent_pProjects, 3);` It's `$recent_projects`, not `$recent_pProjects`. Also, add quotes around your array keys

Comment: Please go and enable proper PHP error reporting first of all - then PHP has a chance to tell you about stuff like this itself.

Comment: @kerbholz i accidentally pasted in the wrong code snippet, i've since updated however that was not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added logic here to filter out the project with the same URL as the page. Then select the random 3 projects to display it. Here is the demo [link](https://3v4l.org/6ATsH)

```
$recent_projects = [
    [
        'project_title'       => 'Project Name1',
        'project_url'         => 'url1'
    ],
    [
        'project_title'       => 'Project Name2',
        'project_url'         => 'url2'
    ],
    [
        'project_title'       => 'Project Name3',
        'project_url'         => 'url3'
    ],
    [
        'project_title'       => 'Project Name4',
        'project_url'         => 'url4'
    ],
    [
        'project_title'       => 'Project Name5',
        'project_url'         => 'url5'
    ]
];
$show_x_projects  = 3; // How may projects to show
$current_page     = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

// remove the project which matches with page url
$filtered_projects = array_filter($recent_projects, function ($project) use ($current_page) {
    return ($project['project_url'] != $current_page);
});

// select random 3 project from filtered projects
$random_projects  = array_rand($filtered_projects, $show_x_projects);

foreach ($random_projects as $index) {
    $item = $filtered_projects[$index];
    echo $item['project_title']; // replace this with hrml code
}
```

There were several issues in the code given in the question

- spelling mistake in variable `$recent_pProjects`
- no code for URL check
- unused variables

Comment: sorry @vinay just i realised i pasted the wrong snippet, i've since updated my original post. will try your code and see how i go. thanks

Comment: @DylanMcleod I can see the updated code, there is some logical issue here. You are first selecting the random three projects and then checking for the URL condition on the selected random projects, which might give you the list of projects less than 3 in the count. I have modified this logic hope this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First...Your array should look like this:

```
<?php

    $recent_projects = [
            [
                'project_img'         => 'assets/img.jpg',
                'project_title'       => 'Project Name',
                'project_cat'         => 'Project Category',
                'project_url'         => 'project-name',
                'project_alttag'      => 'Project Name',
                'project_titletag'    => 'Project name',
                'project_nofollow'    => 'follow'
            ],
            [
                'project_img'         => 'assets/img.jpg',
                'project_title'       => 'Project Name',
                'project_cat'         => 'Project Category',
                'project_url'         => 'project-name',
                'project_alttag'      => 'Project Name',
                'project_titletag'    => 'Project name',
                'project_nofollow'    => 'follow'
            ],
            [
                'project_img'         => 'assets/img.jpg',
                'project_title'       => 'Project Name',
                'project_cat'         => 'Project Category',
                'project_url'         => 'project-name',
                'project_alttag'      => 'Project Name',
                'project_titletag'    => 'Project name',
                'project_nofollow'    => 'follow'
            ],
            [
                'project_img'         => 'assets/img.jpg',
                'project_title'       => 'Project Name',
                'project_cat'         => 'Project Category',
                'project_url'         => 'project-name',
                'project_alttag'      => 'Project Name',
                'project_titletag'    => 'Project name',
                'project_nofollow'    => 'follow'
            ]
        ];

        $show_x_projects  = 3; // How may projects to show
        $i                = 0;
        $current_page     = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        $random_keys= array_rand($recent_projects,3);

    ?>
```

Than for the looping part:

```
<?php
    foreach($random_keys as $key): ?>
            <?php $project = $recent_projects[$key];?>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <figure>
              <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $project["project_img"]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $project["project_alttag"]; ?>" title="<?php echo $project["project_titletag"]; ?>">
              <p></p>
              <figcaption>
                  <h4><span><?php echo $project["project_title"]; ?></span></h4>
                  <p><?php echo $project["project_cat"]; ?></p>
                  <a href="<?php echo $project["project_url"]; ?>" rel="<?php echo $project["project_nofollow"]; ?>"></a>
                  <p class="view-project-link">View Project →</p>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

[Working php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%20$recent_projects%20=%20[%20[%20%27project_img%27%20=%3E%20%27assets/img.jpg%27,%20%27project_title%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Name%27,%20%27project_cat%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Category%27,%20%27project_url%27%20=%3E%20%27project-name%27,%20%27project_alttag%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Name%27,%20%27project_titletag%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20name%27,%20%27project_nofollow%27%20=%3E%20%27follow%27%20],%20[%20%27project_img%27%20=%3E%20%27assets/img.jpg%27,%20%27project_title%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Name%27,%20%27project_cat%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Category%27,%20%27project_url%27%20=%3E%20%27project-name%27,%20%27project_alttag%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Name%27,%20%27project_titletag%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20name%27,%20%27project_nofollow%27%20=%3E%20%27follow%27%20],%20[%20%27project_img%27%20=%3E%20%27assets/img.jpg%27,%20%27project_title%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Name%27,%20%27project_cat%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Category%27,%20%27project_url%27%20=%3E%20%27project-name%27,%20%27project_alttag%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Name%27,%20%27project_titletag%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20name%27,%20%27project_nofollow%27%20=%3E%20%27follow%27%20],%20[%20%27project_img%27%20=%3E%20%27assets/img.jpg%27,%20%27project_title%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Name%27,%20%27project_cat%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Category%27,%20%27project_url%27%20=%3E%20%27project-name%27,%20%27project_alttag%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20Name%27,%20%27project_titletag%27%20=%3E%20%27Project%20name%27,%20%27project_nofollow%27%20=%3E%20%27follow%27%20]%20];%20$show_x_projects%20=%203;%20/*%20How%20may%20projects%20to%20show*/%20$i%20=%200;%20$current_page%20=%20trim($_SERVER[%27REQUEST_URI%27],%20%27/%27);%20$random_keys=%20array_rand($recent_projects,3);%20?%3E%20%3C?php%20foreach($random_keys%20as%20$key):%20?%3E%20%3C?php%20$project%20=%20$recent_projects[$key];?%3E%20%3Cdiv%20class=%22col-sm-12%20col-md-4%22%3E%20%3Cfigure%3E%20%3Cimg%20class=%22img-fluid%22%20src=%22%3C?php%20echo%20$project[%22project_img%22];%20?%3E%22%20alt=%22%3C?php%20echo%20$project[%22project_alttag%22];%20?%3E%22%20title=%22%3C?php%20echo%20$project[%22project_titletag%22];%20?%3E%22%3E%20%3Cp%3E%3C/p%3E%20%3Cfigcaption%3E%20%3Ch4%3E%3Cspan%3E%3C?php%20echo%20$project[%22project_title%22];%20?%3E%3C/span%3E%3C/h4%3E%20%3Cp%3E%3C?php%20echo%20$project[%22project_cat%22];%20?%3E%3C/p%3E%20%3Ca%20href=%22%3C?php%20echo%20$project[%22project_url%22];%20?%3E%22%20rel=%22%3C?php%20echo%20$project[%22project_nofollow%22];%20?%3E%22%3E%3C/a%3E%20%3Cp%20class=%22view-project-link%22%3EView%20Project%20%E2%86%92%3C/p%3E%20%3C/figcaption%3E%20%3C/figure%3E%20%3C/div%3E%20%3C?php%20endforeach;%20?%3E)

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $recent_projects = array(
            array(
                'project_img' => 'assets/img.jpg',
                'project_title' => 'Project Name',
                'project_cat' => 'Project Category',
                'project_url' => 'project-name',
                'project_alttag' => 'Project Name',
                'project_titletag' => 'Project name',
                'project_nofollow' => 'follow'
            ),
            array(
                'project_img' => 'assets/img.jpg',
                'project_title' => 'Project Name',
                'project_cat' => 'Project Category',
                'project_url' => 'project-name',
                'project_alttag' => 'Project Name',
                'project_titletag' => 'Project name',
                'project_nofollow' => 'follow'
            ),
            array(
                'project_img' => 'assets/img.jpg',
                'project_title' => 'Project Name',
                'project_cat' => 'Project Category',
                'project_url' => 'project-name',
                'project_alttag' => 'Project Name',
                'project_titletag' => 'Project name',
                'project_nofollow' => 'follow'
            ),
            array(
                'project_img' => 'assets/img.jpg',
                'project_title' => 'Project Name',
                'project_cat' => 'Project Category',
                'project_url' => 'project-name',
                'project_alttag' => 'Project Name',
                'project_titletag' => 'Project name',
                'project_nofollow' => 'follow'
            )
        );

        $show_x_projects = 3; // How may projects to show
        $i = 0;
        $current_page = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
        $random_projects = array_rand($recent_projects);
        ?>
        <?php $random_projects = array_rand($recent_projects, 3);
        foreach ($random_projects as $index): 
            $item = $recent_projects[$index];
            ?>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <figure>
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $item['project_img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item['project_alttag']; ?>" title="<?php echo $item['project_titletag']; ?>">
                    <p></p>
                    <figcaption>
                        <h4><span><?php echo $item['project_title']; ?></span></h4>
                        <p><?php echo $item['project_cat']; ?></p>
                        <a href="<?php echo $item['project_url']; ?>" rel="<?php echo $item['project_nofollow']; ?>"></a>
                        <p class="view-project-link">View Project →</p>
                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```